# How to get updated value from Dijit.editor and set it to other div

Tags: editor, dojo

I trying to get this script to work, but no success so far.

HTML:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Editor" id="editor"></div>
<div id="target"><div>
```

Script:

```
          dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

            var geteditor = dojo.byId("editor");
            dojo.connect(geteditor, "onChange", function() {
               var a =  dijit.byId("editor").get("value");
               dojo.byId("target").innerHTML= a ; 

            });
          });
```

Does someone can advise me, how to get editor **updated/changed** value from dijit.editor after it changes smth and update other div.innerHTML?
Maybe there is other way? Im new with dojo and javascript acctualy.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to update one value change in another element.  I'm not sure that you can use a dijit.Editor to do something equivalent.  If you need a larger box, just use the style attributes to make the boxes larger...

```
 dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
 dojo.require("dojo.parser");

 dojo.ready(function(){
     dojo.parser.parse();
     var box0 = dijit.byId("value0Box");
     var box1 = dijit.byId("value1Box");
     box1.set("value", box0.get("value") + " modified");
     dojo.connect(box0, "onChange", function(){
         box1.set("value", box0.get("value") + " modified");
     });
 });


<label for="value0Box">A textbox with a value:</label> 
<input id="value0Box" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" value="Some value" data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges:true"></input>
<br>
<label for="value1Box">A textbox set with a value from the above textbox:</label>   
<input id="value1Box" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"></input>
<br>
```

Comment: Ups, my bad here. But problem still remains, couse i wrote code here, didnt copied. So i just missed set attributes.

Comment: @Audrius I changed my answer.  Let me know if you're still having problems.